# How to animate height of bars down in Svelte

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svelte

I am trying to animate the height of bars going down.
I have found a "slide" transition, but not sure how can I reverse it? Currently, the transition is going up. Should I make a custom transition for it? Have a feeling I am missing something basic here. I am very new to Svelte.
Here is the code https://svelte.dev/repl/b869c0da3bdd46389e037b9dd194831f?version=3.32.3

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Not absolutely positive I understand what you're trying to do in your `updateData` method and how you would expect that to translate into an animation.

As it is, by filtering your dataset, you're *removing* half the data points, so you can't really expect a smooth transition for that.

I've modified the `updateData` function to keep the original number of data points while modifiying the values of the first three points:

```js
function updateData() {
  // points = points.filter(d => d.year > 2000)
  points = points.map(d => ({ ...d, birthrate: d.year > 2000 ? d.birthrate : 0 }))
}
```

As you can see [here](https://svelte.dev/repl/fc633d59c07a4020937a5862e7b91438?version=3.32.3), the animation is smooth and probably closer to what you expected?

Comment: Thank you! Yes, the transition animation is exactly what I expected. However, I also wanted the data to update. By the update function I actually just filter out data so the values would update. I was looking for something like exit in the enter/update/exit pattern in d3

Comment: While I am familiar with Svelte, I am not very familiar with D3 ;) However, I looked up the pattern you mentioned. I think the idea would be to have composite animations: for the 'exit' transition, first set the bar to 0 (the animation I've shown), *then* remove the bar that was zeroed. For the 'enter' transition, first add a new bar with a value of 0, *then* set the value to its proper amount. The key here is to chain the animations, so trigger the second part of your composition once the first is complete. This should be do-able with events.

Comment: Actually, it is much simpler to chain the data point updates using `setTimeout` in the `dataUpdate` function: https://svelte.dev/repl/fc633d59c07a4020937a5862e7b91438?version=3.32.3. Is this what you were looking for? You can play around with the time out value to chain the animations faster or to force a slight delay between them.

Comment: Sorry, shouldn't have assumed your knowledge of D3! Yes, the second one is what I had in mind! I actually wanted to make them simultaneous, but this is nicely achieved by reducing the time in the setTimeout function. I think I understand the logic in Svelte a bit better now, it is a bit of a change of thinking from D3 way. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome! I think the main takeaway here is that in order for the vertical bar animation to play, you *have* to transition through a state where the `y` value is 0. The second takeaway is the idea of composition when your animation has multiple segments/components (i.e. in your case a vertical animation + an enter/exit animation).